# Запросом в истории изменений вывести только пользователей с заданным переходом статуса

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица с историей изменения статуса пользователей.
Таблица имеет вид: `(id, id_polz, data, status)`

Нужно отобразить всех пользователей у которых статус изменился, например, с 2 на 5.

```
select id_polz, prew_status 
from (
    select id_polz, lag (status,1) over (order by data) as prew_status 
    from Table_name 
    group by status, id, id_polz having status = 5
) temp_table 
where prew_status = 2
```

Пробовал без подзапроса, но не могу сделать фильтр по столбцу, в котором высчитывается `LAG`, возникает ошибка использования оконных функций.

Желательно либо на Oracle, либо на MSSQL.

Comment: Использование LAG() - решение верное. Строите CTE (секция WITH), добавляете в данные именно LAG(status,1), **указав правильные параметры в OVER**. А в основном запросе просто фильтруете по паре значений status и LAG(status).

Comment: Всё получилось! Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Конструкция `GROUP BY ... HAVING ...` явно не к месту. Простое решение с функций [LAG](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LAG.html):

```sql
with userhist (id, userid, status, changed) as (
    select 1, 1, 1, date'2020-01-10' from dual union all
    select 2, 1, 2, date'2020-01-12' from dual union all
    select 3, 1, 5, date'2020-01-15' from dual union all
    select 4, 2, 1, date'2020-01-20' from dual union all
    select 5, 2, 2, date'2020-01-22' from dual union all
    select 6, 2, 3, date'2020-01-23' from dual union all
    select 7, 2, 5, date'2020-01-25' from dual) 
select userid, status, prevstatus, changed 
from (
    select userid, status, changed, lag (status) over (order by changed) as prevstatus 
    from userhist) 
where status = 5 and prevstatus = 2 
/

    USERID     STATUS PREVSTATUS CHANGED            
---------- ---------- ---------- -------------------
         1          5          2 2020-01-15 00:00:00
```